# Where can I find a proof of Hurwitz's Irrational Number Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I'm trying to find a proof of Hurwitz's approximation theorem, but to no avail so far.

The theorem is that for any irrational number $\alpha$ there are infinite rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ such that
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}$$

Any hints or links would be much appreciated!

Comment: [*LeVeque*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTWoAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&lpg=PT195&dq=proof+of+Hurwitz%27s+Irrational+Number+Theorem?&source=bl&ots=DGxwSS78cO&sig=7GdyTn6RPp2qa3h3vXESEAK5sL0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4r-brpfjJAhUUVGMKHS-9AoU4ChDoAQhAMAc#v=onepage&q=proof%20of%20Hurwitz's%20Irrational%20Number%20Theorem%3F&f=false)

Comment: Ivan Niven's book _Diophantine Approximations_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Have you looked at the references on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory))?

Comment: @Variable the link that you gave me 1) has the proof, and 2) is free (at least for viewing the sample), so if you give that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The theorem does not say anything about infinite rational numbers.  I don't know what an infinite rational number is.  It says there are _infinitely many_ rational numbers satisfying that inequality.  It is incorrect to write "infinite" if you mean "infinitely many". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hardy and Wright

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a proof in Topics in Number Theory, Volumes I and II
 By William J. LeVeque. Both volumes are available as a Dover book and are inexpensive.

Here is a [*link*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTWoAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&lpg=PT195&dq=proof+of+Hurwitz%27s+Irrational+Number+Theorem?&source=bl&ots=DGxwSS78cO&sig=7GdyTn6RPp2qa3h3vXESEAK5sL0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4r-brpfjJAhUUVGMKHS-9AoU4ChDoAQhAMAc#v=onepage&q=proof%20of%20Hurwitz's%20Irrational%20Number%20Theorem%3F&f=false) where you can see the proof.